# How do I insert with pdo by getting variables from form?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

How do I to make an insert from a form by PDO it gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on string
```

Here is my code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$name = $_POST['subname'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO customers(name,subname,phone)VALUES(:name,:subname,:phone)";
$sql->bindParam(':name', $name);
$sql->bindParam(':subname', $subname);
$sql->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
$sql->bindParam(':telefono', $telefono);
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: The `bindParam()` method is used incorrectly here. Please see a tutorial such as this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp. Look for "Example (PDO with Prepared Statements)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to work with your PDO statement, and first prepare your query:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$name = $_POST['subname'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO customers(name,subname,phone)VALUES(:name,:subname,:phone)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':name', $name);
$sth->bindParam(':subname', $subname);
$sth->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
$sth->bindParam(':telefono', $telefono);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: An even better habit to get into is to ditch the `$sql` declaration and supply the string directly to `prepare()`.